# How to match regex in this case

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a regex with the following phrases:

```
RENT3 - LOCALIZA
HGRE11 - FII HG REAL
HGLG11 - FII CSHG LOG
HGBS11 - FII CSHGSHOP
KNRI11 - FII KINEA
NTCO3 - GRUPO NATURAON      NM
ITUB3 - ITAUUNIBANCO
ITSA4 - ITAUSA
ITSA4 - ITAUSA
```

I have trying using `\s-\s(\w+)\w*$` and at the moment is getting some lines as you can check in this example:

https://regex101.com/r/I4JkVP/2

How can I getting all lines?

My objetive with this regex is to remove all words after the first word, for example:

```
RENT3 - LOCALIZA
```

after keeps only word: "RENT3".

Comment: Your regexp won't work if there's a space in the second part.

Comment: Not a foolproof pattern because you didn't provide enough info but you may start with something like this: `\s-\s(\w+)(?:\s+\w*)*$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WhX3hk/1

Comment: I understand and thank you guys for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Instead just capture the first word as a group:

```
(?<identifier>\w+).*
```

Then for each line call match and if it matches, then:

```
String identifier = matcher.group(“identifier”)
```

Much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(?=\s-\s).*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLfn5k/1)

Answer (score 0):

To match all first words:

```
^\w+(?=\s+-)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?=\s+-)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is 1+ whitespace chars and `-`

For your example data, you can also leave out the `^`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jOmST4/1)

---

To remove all after the first word which is followed by a hyphen, you can use a capturing group and use that in the replacement.

```
^(\w+)\s*-.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zosLwy/1)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the last **\w** with **.** and works.